# Find the row with Maximum Count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, count

I need to find the row with maximum count. There's only one table, so it should be easy, but it isn't.
Below is the content of table:

```
+------+------+------+
| row1 | row2 | row3 |
+------+------+------+
|    3 |    2 |    1 |
|    6 |    4 |    5 |
|    6 |    2 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
```

I need to find maximum count item for row1:
Using: 
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS c, row1 AS name 
    FROM draw 
    GROUP BY name;
Give me the result:

```
+------+------+
|   c  | name |
+------+------+
|    1 |    3 |
|    2 |    6 |
+------+------+
```

But I want to display only one row with the maximum "c":

```
+------+------+
|   c  | name |
+------+------+
|    2 |    6 |
+------+------+
```

Using: 
    SELECT MAX(c), name (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS c, row1 AS name 
        FROM draw GROUP BY name
    ) AS counts;

Give me result:

```
+------+------+
|   c  | name |
+------+------+
|    2 |    3 |
+------+------+
```

It means that it gives maximum count (c), but give first number in name row.

Is there way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want, but your requirements are a little unclear.  If this was any other platform you could use windowing functions would would be better.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS c, row1
  FROM draw 
  GROUP BY row1
) as Sub1
WHERE Sub.c = (
  SELECT Max(c) 
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM draw 
    GROUP BY row1
  ) as Sub2
) as Sub3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select top 1 row1, count(*)
from draw
group by row1
order by count(*) desc
```

Order by the count descending (i.e. highest count first) and take the first one only.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
SELECT COUNT(  `row1` ) AS c,  `row1` 
FROM  `draw` 
GROUP BY  `row1` 
ORDER BY  `row1` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If two or more row1 values have the same count, your solution only shows one of them.

Comment: @MaZak it works so long as you don't care about ties, and so long as the row1 value returned, arbitrarily, is the one with the highest sort value (currently descending).